# Selection not working Collection view embedded in container view

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I have a container view at the bottom of the screen which overlay on top of the main view. A Collection view is embedded in the container which hidden when the view first load. On the main view controller, I have a tap gesture IBaction which unhide/hide the container view when the main view is tapped.

I have another tap gesture IBaction on the imageView in the collection view. I want to load new content in the main view when the collection view cell(image) is tapped.

My problem is the collectionview(container) is hidden again when I tap on the collection view image. It appears to me that the tap gesture on the main view has priority over the tap gesture on the collection view. I have also tried didselecteditematindexpath instead of tap gesture on the collection view controller but it also does not work. I only want the container to be hidden if I tap anywhere on the main view but not the container/collection view. I am at a lost, please help.

I want to mention that swiping the collection view is working fine without additional coding.

Comment: can u put your code???

Comment: you can use tag to distinguish between tap on main view and tap on imageview! when tapped on mainview check for view and if it is not containerview than hide containerview else load new content on main view

Comment: The only code I have on the main controller is @IBAction func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        containerView.hidden = !containerView.hidden
    }

Comment: and on the collectionview controller, i have another @IBAction func handleTap2(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        println("Collection View Tap")
    }

Comment: Saurabh: the problem is the tap action on the collection view controller is not triggered. I am not even at the point where I need to distinguish which view is been tapped.

Comment: check imageview property userInteractionEnable is set or not?

Comment: The only codes I added are the 2 IBActions on the 2 view controllers respectively. The rest of the codes are bare bone from the UIView controller and UICollectionView Controller.

Comment: Saurabh: you are the best. I swear I have checked the imageview property userInteractionEnable but it did not work. Somehow, it works this time because you told me and I tried again, making sure the property is really set before I run the code. No idea why it did not work the hundred times I tried. What matters is it works this time. Thank you so much. You save my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check for Imageview's Property userInteractionEnabled**

```
 containerView.tag = 1234;
 -(IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
 {
      if(recognizer.view.tag != 1234)
      {
           //hide container view
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
give tag to the imageView like 1001

and in handleTap you can check like

if(sender.tag==1001){
NSLog(@"Image Tapped");
}
else{
NSLog(@"Other area of view tapped");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on tap gesture for collection view go for delegate Method didSelectItem